# How to configure Upstart for Node js to respawn the process that is killed due to some error

Tags: 14.04, upstart, nodejs

I am new to Server side of things .

I want respawn my killed node js server which occurred due to some error.

I looked into forever but i want  to use upstart any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can read the official documentation under respawn chapter:

> http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn

If you already have a config file for your node service, how may have only to add the following line :

```
respawn limit COUNT INTERVAL | unlimited
```

Where COUNT is the number of respawn until the service is kept death (or replace by unlimited) and interval is the number of second between a retries (useful to prevent too many restart and killing your server resources if the service doesn't stay up).